# UILabel Vertical align missing space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I've used `UILabel` for showing text with `vertical alignment`. I'm showing text as **character by character** with vertical alignment. Actually It's an moving text by alignment with `CABasicAnimation`. But my problem here is

1. Each line should `show one character`, but when I try stretch label width to
   show single character, Some character is **wiped partially**. see screen
   shot of xib(sample with small text).. Or try to extend frame size, some row show single   character and some shows **double character**.
2. **Space is missing between words**. see screenshot.

How can I fix it with my xib? Answer also acceptable with programmatically.

[image]

**Note:** Text used in this example "Some text  with long".

Comment: Insert new line character `\n` between letters

Comment: I already use that. But character wrap didn't take that escape character. please try with your xcode. You can see that issue.

Comment: @iDev see that my screen shot if i'm using space what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need vertical align. Just make the UILabel wider and input a \n after every character of the string.

```
        NSString *longString = @"This is a very very long string";

        NSString *labelString = @"";

        self.label.text = labelString;
        self.label.numberOfLines = 500; //just put a big number or calculate something

        for (int n=longString.length - 1; n > -1; --n) {

            labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [longString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(n, 1)], labelString];

                self.label.text = labelString;

        }
```

Comment: See I want vertical align with my project. Because I haven't enough height with view. So I want to show some flash news by vertically. Did you get it?

Comment: Yes I get it. Still don't think you need vertical align. just add the characters one by one that would give you the effect. you can even warp it in a animateWithDuration to make it more elegant.

Comment: Did you mean horizontally?

Comment: No I mean vertically. Will look just like your picture but without the issues. Think about it this way: You have a UIString with the full text and another that is empty. You set the UILabel to the empty one. Then you start a loop: on each iteration you take the last character of the first string - the loop number and add it to the second string then refresh the UILabel. I can write you the code if you need.

Comment: what do you mean by UIString? Could you update your answer with this code? I didn't understand what you've tried..

Comment: Take a look at the edit. You can now add animation to make it happen slowly letter by letter it will look like a ticker.